# Firefox's secure connection favicon is gone, how do I fix this?

Tags: firefox, ssl

There used to be a larger favicon when I connected to secure websites.

But now when I go to a secure website, there is a blink in the favicon, like it shows the large favicon for an instant, and then it goes back to the normal, smaller favicon.

I can't recall if I did this on purpose to have more visibility, or it just started happening. Either way, I want it back.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox 4 this feature was removed for some reason. I don't like it too, and most people found this feature useful. I hope they will bring it back, there are already threads about it in the Mozilla Firefox forums. In the meanwhile, a quick add-ons search in the Firefox website  found me the [Padlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/padlock-icon/) add-on. I am not sure how it works, but it seems promising, at least for the meanwhile.